# d3 Exit / Update function in animation

Tags: animation, d3.js, transition

I am trying to do an animation that shows data from ten different points. The graphic is coded so that the sensors (displayed through circles) change their color and size depending on the overall data obtained over one hour (total number of entries and average of speed).

Through this entry ([Transition not working d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474747/transition-not-working-d3/44394866#44394866)) and the code from this simulation of Gapminder (https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/), I have been able to animate the chart. However, because of the structure of the code, the exit and update function do not work. The first entry in the data at Hour 1 only has one object and therefore only one circle is drawn. This circle gets updated through time, but the other sensors are not drawn (and therefore not updated).

I am considering recreating a first empty object for each sensor to draw them at the beginning of the animation. However, I would like to avoid that.

The code is this:

```
//FUNCTION TO GET THE DATA BY HOUR
function getDataByHour (hour) {
    var allBridges = new Array();
    var found;
    for (b = 0; b < boatsByHour.length; b++){
        bridges.forEach(function(br,i){
            if (boatsByHour[b].sensorID== br.id){
                xy = projection([br.longitude, br.latitude])}
        });
        if (boatsByHour[b].hour == hour){
            found = true;
            bridgeNumber = boatsByHour[b].sensorID;
            allBridges.push({
                "numberBoats": (boatsByHour[b].numberBoats),
                "speed": (boatsByHour[b].speedAvg),
                "bridge": boatsByHour[b].sensorID,
                "longitude": xy[0],
                "latitude": xy[1],
                "hour": boatsByHour[b].hour
            })
        }
    }
    return allBridges;
}

//SENSORS
var sensor = plot.append("g")
    .attr("class","bridges")
    .selectAll(".sensors")
    .data(getDataByHour(timeRange[0]))
    .call(animateSensors)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class","sensors")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i){return d.longitude})
    .attr("cy", function(d,i){return d.latitude})
    .on("mouseover",function(d){console.log(d)});

sensor.exit().remove();

plot
    .transition()
    .duration(300000)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .tween("hour", tweenHour)

//FUNCTION THAT UPDATES THE ANIMATION
function animateSensors (sensor){
    sensor
        .attr("r",function(d){return radiusScale(d.numberBoats)})
        .style("fill",function(d){return colorScale(d.speed)});
}

function tweenHour(){
    var hour = d3.interpolateNumber (timeRange[0],timeRange[1]);

    return function(h){
        displayHour(hour(h))}
}

function displayHour(hour) {
    sensor.data(getDataByHour(Math.floor(hour))).call(animateSensors);
}
```

I have tried different ways of including the enter() and exit (). If I add the enter() and append the circles inside the 'animateSensors' function, all the circles (sensors) are drawn. However they are not being updated, so at the end, I get thousands of circles drawn in the SVG even if the exit().remove() update is in it.

Thanks

Comment: It's the function that updates the radius and fill attributes of the circles
`function animateSensors (sensor){
    sensor
        .attr("r",function(d){return radiusScale(d.numberBoats)})
        .style("fill",function(d){return colorScale(d.speed)});
}
`

Comment: The position of the call does not change the result (only one circle being displayed). I have checked and the issue is that all the data is going directly to that circle, instead of drawing the other ones

Comment: Yes, `allBridges` is an array of objects. The selection of those objects depends on a time attribute `hour`

Comment: The problem here is that `sensor` is an "enter" selection, and you can't call `exit()` over an "enter" selection. So, the approach should be creating an "update" selection, which is: `var sensor = plot.append("g").attr("class","bridges").selectAll(".sensors").data(getDataByHour(timeRange[0]))`, an "enter" selection, which is: `sensor.enter().append("circle").etc...` and an "exit" selection, which is: `sensor.exit().remove()`.

Comment: yeah, I tried that yesterday, but if when I do that there is no that entering the `animateSensors` function at all. I had `sensor ... ..data(getDataByHour(timeRange[0]));` then `sensorEnter` (without calling the animation); then `sensor.exit().remove();` and, finally `  sensor.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .call(animateSensors)`

Comment: Well, I can tell you that, right now, `sensor` is just an "enter" selection. Can you create a working demo with data? If you create a jsfiddle/plunker/codepen/whatever you will get help faster.

Comment: there you go [link] (http://plnkr.co/edit/PehkOi6TPiu2MsI8MXtr)

Comment: i've also reviewed the code again and the enter is also like that in https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now it works. Instead of calling the first part of the data (where there is only 1 circle is drawn instead of the total 10), I had to call data that had data for all the circles (like the last point):

```
var sensor = plot.append("g")
        .attr("class","bridges")
        .selectAll(".bridge")
        .data(getDataByHour(timeRange[1])) // instead of getDataByHour(timeRange[0])
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class",function(d){return "bridge " + d.bridge})
        .attr("cx", function(d,i){return d.longitude})
        .attr("cy", function(d,i){return d.latitude})
        .on("mouseover",function(d){console.log(d)});
```

The animation starts correctly thanks to the function tweenHour

```
function tweenHour(){
        var hour = d3.interpolateNumber (timeRange[0],timeRange[1]);

        return function(h){
            displayHour(hour(h))}
    }
```